# php if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using a twitter class to post updates to my account for this I have removed my twitter credentials so I am aware that XXXXX is wrong. I am able to parse the text from the remote xml file. This xml files text always reads "There are no active codes." So in my if statement i said that if the xml file reads "There are no active codes." i dont want to post anything to my twitter, but if it changes to anything else then i would like to parse that information and post it to my twitter. So today when there was an update to the xml file nothing happened. I know that the twitter portion is correct because I have a similar script that does not use an if statement and it posts fine. Once i introduced the if statement i have run into problem of not being able to post. So what can i do to post to twitter only when the xml file changes from "There are no active codes." to anything else?

```
// Parse Message
$source = file_get_contents('WEBSITE_URL_GOES_HERE');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$match = $xml->xpath("//code_message");


//Twitter class (Updating status)
require_once 'twitteroauth.php';
//Twitter credentials
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "XXXXXX");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "XXXXXX");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "XXXXXX-XXXXXX");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "XXXXXX");
// Verify credentials
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');


//If Statement
if ( $match[0] == "There are no active codes." ) {
    /* Do Nothing */;
} else {
    $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'New Code Available - ' . $match[0] ));
    return $connection;
}
```

var_dump of the $match array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { [0]=> string(32) "There are no active codes." } }
```

Comment: Can I have a look at match array?

Comment: @samir chauhan array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { [0]=> string(32) "There are no active codes." } }

Comment: That's what the comments are meant for.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a string comparison function.
like strcmp : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

```
if (strcmp($match,"There are no active codes.") != 0 )
{
    $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'New Code Available - ' . $match[0] ));
    return $connection;
}
```

Comment: Am i helping a twitter spam bot ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add some debugging code and check what's going on? Echo you `$match[0]` and check what's in there. It's hard to imagine "if" being broken, isn't it? Maybe `var_dump($match)` just to check what's going on. Then you should probably either fix your condition or fix the retrieval of $match.

Check your array: the `[0]` element is an object, not a string. You need to get the first element of that object, if you know what I mean.

You are comparing:

```
Object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { [0]=> string(32) "There are no active codes." }
```

to

```
"There are no active codes."
```

Which is obviously not the same.

I can't test it from here, but check out the manual of simpelXMLElement: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

You should probably get away with a simple call. Just check out what kind of object you have. A simple example would be something like "$match[0]->childname", but I can't quickly see what the childname is. Check out the manual for some sort of getchild or something, shouldn't be too tricky

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { [0]=> string(32) "There are no active codes." } }

Comment: ah, well, there you are then :)

Comment: is it possible to convert to a string from an oject?